# One field in form doesn't validate in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

The problem is that "confirmPassword" never pass through validation.
Yes, there are also all getters and setters.

The "test" and "password" variables validate OK.

I cannot see a difference between those variables, except that test is of type text and confirmPassword if of type password.

The message is "This value should not be blank" even when I do enter text into this field.

What is wrong here?

/////////////////////User entity class (part of):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
 * @Assert\NotBlank (groups={"registration"})
 */
private $password;

/**
* @Assert\NotBlank(
*  groups={"registration"},
* )
*/  
private $confirmPassword;

/**
* @Assert\NotBlank(
*  groups={"registration"},
 */
private $test;
```

//////////////////////////////////user type class:

```
class Register extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
        ));
    }  

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username',TextType::class, array('error_bubbling'=>false,'label'=>'Login'))
            ->add('email',  TextType::class, array('error_bubbling'=>false, 'label' => 'E-mail'))
            ->add('password',PasswordType::class, array('error_bubbling'=>false,'label' => 'password'))
            ->add('confirmPassword',PasswordType::class, array('error_bubbling'=>false,'label' => 'password confimation')) 
            ->add('test',TextType::class, array('error_bubbling'=>false,'label' => 'test'))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

//////////////////And finally, the submit function:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request, $done = 0)
{
    $user = new \AppBundle\Entity\User();

    $form = $this->createForm(Register::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $validator = $this->get('validator');

        if($form->isValid()){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_register',array('done' => 1));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('front/users/register.html.twig', [
        'form'=>$form->createView(),
        'done'=>$done,
        'errors' => array()
    ]);
}
```

**Edit**: added getters and setters. Please notice that a vertical scrollbar appeared.

///////////getters and setters

```
 public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt() {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        $ret_val = array();
        $roles = $this->getUserRoles();

        if($roles) {
            foreach($roles as $Role) {
                $ret_val[] = $Role->getRoleName();
            }
        }
        return $ret_val;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }

    public function getConfirmPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setConfirmPassword($password) {
        $this->confirmPassword = $password;
        return $this;
    }  


/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setEmail($email) {
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}



 /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setTest($test){
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function getTest(){
        return $this->test;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please also show the getters and setters of your entity?

Comment: What about using the `repeated` type for confirming the second password? That way Symfony will compare the passwords itself: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

Comment: @xabbuh, hi, can you please look at my updated question, I added the getters and setters.

Comment: @Rvanlaak: Yes, I've seen it, it just that I'm learning Symfony and I try to understand the problem.

Comment: At least, `getConfirmPassword()` does not return the expected property (it returns `$password`).

Comment: @xabbuh - thank you! I don't know how I missed it, I was pretty sure this is Symfony - related and not such a stupid mistake :) 
If you answer I will accept it (if my reputation is high enough, because I registered  about two weeks ago).

Comment: Ah, did it solve your issue?

Comment: @xabbuh: Yes, you did, thanks:)

Comment: Sounds a bit weird though as the message shouldn't appear when you entered the "normal" password (because the value returned by `getConfirmPassword()` wasn't blank then.

Comment: Yes I thought about exactly this - so I checked a few times and it does work o_O

I will make some tests now.

Comment: Well, after investigation, when I added " var_dump($this->password) " in getConfirmPassword function, it is not called upon opening the page, but, when doing submit it is called twice, at first it is == null, then with the correct (entered) string. So I don't understand it. I spent a loooot of time, just because of a typo (or rather because of ctrl+c ctrl+v). On the other hand I don't know how a framework could help me handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getConfirmPassword()` method does not return the expected property (it returns `$password`).

Comment: Thanks! As I expected I have too low reputation to actually accept, but AFAIK, since I clicked it this will happen when I'll have higher reputation.